# Avoid instantiate Generics without defining the class

Tags: java, lombok

I have this class defined

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "id" })
@Builder(toBuilder=true)
@Wither
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class Hostel<T> {
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to avoid the instantiation without defining the class like this

```
new Hostel<>();
```

and always force to instantiate like:

```
new Hostel<GuestAndHouse>();
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid a diamond operator, or just trying to make it so it's only a generic argument of a specific bound of types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prohibit this syntactical variant. For example this

`Hostel<GuestAndHouse> h = new Hostel<>();`

is only a simplified syntax for that:

`Hostel<GuestAndHouse> h = new Hostel<GuestAndHouse>();`

But it is the same thing. The type variable `T` is still defined here. The compiler can infer the type from the context, so you need not write it down.

It is another thing than a raw type like this:

`Hostel h = new Hostel();`

Here the type variable has not been given a real type. This should be avoided, but the Java compiler allows it for backward compatibility with code that has been written before generics were present in java (generics have been introduced in 1.5).